# How do I track logins, connections, user accounts, queries, ...?

Tags: sql-server

I am a BI person who has been asked to step in and pretend I am a DBA.  I am not a novice with databases but AM a novice at the admin type stuff.

We have a SQL Server database that is going to be decommissioned.  I have been asked to determine who is using the server, the databases that are being used and the queries being run.

So far I've created a table to track server logins as well as check number of connections as referred to @ http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3171/identify-sql-server-databases-that-are-no-longer-in-use/

However, once I had that info I was asked to track:

- The user account or credentials being used to connect to the server
- the database(s) being queried
- The IP address or DNS name from which the connection was made
- The SQL being used

They want to know specifically who is using any databases on the server so they can determine which need to be migrated and who they need to contact as the database is migrated.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: The entire instance is going to be decommissioned? or just one DB?

Comment: The entire server will be decommissioned.  The databases that are still being used will be moved.  I need to figure out which are still being used and by whom.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you to run a `server side trace` - for your entire business life cycle. There might be cases where some reports are ran end of month or end of quarter.

So you will need below event in a server side trace `11,13,16,19,33,37,61,162` with these columns `1,6,8,10,11,12,14,27,35,40`.

You can filter out stuff that you dont need using `sp_trace_setevent` (note that it is announced deprecated).

Alternatively you can use [Extended events - Tracking SQL Server Database Usage](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/tracking-sql-server-database-usage/).

***Note***: Currently in my environment, I am using Server side trace and its a very low impact. Also, I have a job that dumps the profiler info into a table for analysis.

You can have below table structure for loading trace data :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[login_trace](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ServerName] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [HostName] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [ApplicationName] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [DatabaseName] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [LoginName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

You can adjust it as per your requirement.

Comment: I like this approach.  We recently decommed one of our boxes and notified everyone for a month or so that the application that used that box would no longer work.  We ran traces, monitored activity (session counts) and, eventually, turned the lights off.  We got a handful of calls from the field wondering why the application wasnt working all of a sudden. Sometimes, after giving fair notice, you may just need to turn the lights off and see who calls. Be prepared for that as, undoubtedly, you will have people that will ignore your emails about the box being turned off.

Comment: I do something very similar on all of my servers that I can get away with it (most).  In order to summarize the data I only keep the last occurrence of a given permission hit per host, login, application, DB & object.  The table I store the data in has some significant growth at first but after a couple of days the storage growth drops to almost nothing.  I do have some performance hit during the summarizing code.  Takes about 1-5 minutes every hour.

Comment: I started the profiler yesterday.  It is not server-side, it is running locally and going over the network to the server.

I realize that means a bigger impact on server performance but it is not highly used as is so was not so worried about that.  

Thank you all for your suggestions and insights.

Comment: @Mark-DBAApprentice I would suggest to follow best practice from the start. A profiler trace has a higher impact -[Performance Impact: Profiler Tracing vs. Server Side SQL Tracing](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2007/08/01/trace-profiler-test.aspx). What you can do is to have a server side trace running and once it reaches a certain threshold (e.g. 200MB) wrap it and start a new one. Also, you can use [Using WMI alerts to import SQL Server Default Trace events](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3183/using-wmi-alerts-to-import-sql-server-default-trace-events/).

Comment: @Mark-DBAApprentice If you feel that my answer has addressed your question, please upvote / mark as answer.